# PHP curl -- Using Variable for CURLOPT_USERPWD

Tags: php, curl

Have an issue I am not able to find out. I have a perfectly working curl function here:

```
    function curl_get($url, array $get = NULL, array $options = array())
{
    $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url. (strpos($url, '?') === FALSE ? '?' : ''). http_build_query($get),
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'user:pass'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults));
    if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch))
    {
        trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

My error occurs when I try to use a variable as the value for `CURLOPT_USERPWD` in the format of:
`$key = "user:pass";`

Making it `CURLOPT_USERPWD => $key`

The request is not authenticating at all. Am I missing something here when using a variable for the authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed one more param in `CURL` (i.e) `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH`

So your code should be like below,

```
$defaults = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url. (strpos($url, '?') === FALSE ? '?' : ''). http_build_query($get),
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'user:pass'
);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The function was working as displayed. The error occurs when using $key for CURLOPT_USERPWD, and I still have no idea why.

Comment: i didn't get you. what and where you used $key?

Comment: Sorry. $key is simply: 
`$key = "user:pass";`
So my code no longer works when I change the function to say:
`CURLOPT_USERPWD => $key`

Comment: can i have your skypeID please?

Comment: Sorry I don't have skype :/
For now I am using the workaround I posted below. There just seems to be a core issue with the URL not being formatted when using a string variable for the USERPWD. I say this because the response given back is 404, and not 403

Comment: Can you please check the url in broswer by giving your username/pwd and whether it allows that or not?

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens when You are passing value for `CURLOPT_USERPWD` as `$key`?

Comment: Yes exactly. I've worked around this by just formatting the url as:
`https://$user.':'.$pass.'@'.$url`

Comment: is key value is like this $key=$user.':'.$pass

Comment: No, its just simply:
`$key = "john:password123"; `

Answer (score 1):

Also ran into the problem today.

Using CURLOPT_USERPWD in curl_setopt_array() does not work, maybe a bug?

Calling curl_setopt manually fixes the problem:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pass");
```